# What is the meaning of the "v1.1" in Google Play Purchase API

Tags: google-api, in-app-purchase, version

When I was looking for the Google IAP, I found a different point.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/ v1.1 /applications/

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/ v2 /applications/
```

What is the meaning of the "v1.1" and "v2"?

Is that a '**Google-API** version'? Or a '**Android-Publisher** version'?

Can someone please explain the exact meaning of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the version of [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/), which is a Google API.

You should use the V2 API now, which has many more features than the legacy 1.1 API.